# Model with relationship is returning data from both table CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, relationship, cakephp-2.4, has-one

I'm new at CakePHP and i'm facing some trouble with relationship Models. I have two models with relationship, Employee `hasOne` User.
When i use find method, it returns all data from both table.

Example: `$this->Employee->find('all');` returns Employee data and User data.

Any idea how to return only Employee data?

**Edit**

Searching for another question in cakePHP's docs, i found a more properly resolution for this question.

Before use find() method, just place `$this-Model->unbindModel()`. Right after use a find() method, the Model will back to association defined as default.

More info here: [API CakePHP UnbindModel](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_unbindModel)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230013/missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-grupo-cakephp/23268677#23268677) - or simply read about recursive/containable in the book.

Comment: See [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562128/when-not-to-use-containable-behavior-in-cakephp-2-x) after you read up a bit about recursive/containable as AD7six said.

Comment: I set recursive as -1 and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->Employee->recursive = -1;
$this->Employee->find('all');
```